# Team Foundation Server build is transforming web.config TWICE, and the second time is wrong

Tags: msbuild, web-config, transform, tfsbuild, msdeploy

I have a TFS build definition set up with the following information in the Process -> Advanced -> MSBuild Arguments section: (the [] bracketed values are omitted in this post for security)

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=True 
/p:MSDeployPublishMethod=RemoteAgent 
/p:MSDeployServiceUrl=[URL] 
/p:DeployIisAppPath=[IISPATH] 
/p:UserName=[USERNAME] 
/p:Password=[PASSWORD]
/p:CreatePackageOnPublish=True 
/p:DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish 
/p:Configuration=Development
```

Here's the issue I have. I have many configurations set up in my web project, and the Development configuration is one of them. If I leave off the "/p:Configuration=Development" and build the project, which then auto-deploys to our dev environment, the web.config transform is wrong. It's replacing my connection string info with the information from another configuration.

If I put the "/p:Configuration=Development" back into the MSBuild arg list and open the web.config file in VS2010 during the build process, the first time the web.config is changed outside my IDE, I can see that the appropriate web.config transform has been made in accordance with the Development configuration, but then the web.config file is changed AGAIN, and it's back to the improper configuration.

My thought here is that when leaving the "/p:Configuration=Development" on, MSBuild is getting it right, but whatever process that is called from MSBuild (I'm assuming MSDeploy) to actually deploy the site to the server is getting it wrong.

Oh, and I'm using an IIS6 server, not IIS7, so any IIS7-specific functionality won't really help me.

Any ideas here of how to fix this problem?

Comment: Is it wrong after deployment or before? The transformed config in the drop folder does not include connection string transformations. They are left as MSDEPLOY parameters.

Comment: John, so when in the process do the connection string transformations happen? As part of the MSBuild process, or during the call from MSBuild to MSDeploy? FYI, I'm relying on the .cmd file generated via TFS Team Build, plus the MSBuild Args above that are set in the MSBuild Arguments location in the build definition.

Comment: It happens during msdeploy. Actually the transformation has already taken place but for connection strings the result is in the parameters.xml file. Please answer whether the transform is wrong _after_ deployment.

Comment: John, yes, it's wrong after deployment. Since the web.config changes twice, once about half-way through the build kicked off by TFS, and the second time when the build finished and then is deployed, and b/c the web.configs first change is correct, but the second change in in-correct, I'm making the assumption that it's after deployment. There is a SetParameters.xml file in the same directory where the .zip package is created (also, the TFS Build generated .cmd file is in there as well), is this the parameters xml file you're referring too?

Comment: Yes, that's the file. I found this myself. After deployment the config is correct. Before, it caused me a heart attack.

Comment: yes, but in my case the opposite is true. Before deployment, it's right, after deployment it's incorrect.

Comment: All I can think of is to check the parameters file. Maybe it's the parameters that are incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT - Fix
So, some colleagues and I spent some time on this and eventually rebuilt our environments for an unrelated reason.  After rebuilding, we started to see the same thing happening.  We took a look at the IIS Temporary Compressed Files (C:\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files) folder and noticed a lot of old info being stored. We deleted everything from that folder and ran iisreset, and the build worked as expected.

-- Original Post
I am having the exact same issue. I have looked at every output file I can think of on the build server and they are all correct.  However, when msdeploy is called, the transform seems to happen (based on modified date) but is done wrong.  I have also tried grabbing the deployment.zip and importing application on the web sever, which does deploy correctly.  Does anyone know how to intercept the msdeploy call from the build server to see what exactly the command contains.  I have tried procmon, but not having much luck.